# Use an ambient transaction for single DbCommands

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions, ado.net

I'm using Entity Framework and have just learned about the `TransactionScope` class from `System.Transactions`. These ambient transactions seem to be used automatically for all new database connections that are opened within the transaction scope. People who use this seem to use short-lived database connections as well. It seems that multiple connections can be part of the same transaction that way.

But I need to use transactions as well for a few low-level commands on an existing database connection. I'm used to the more traditional approach where you open a database connection, keep it for the runtime of the application (mostly desktop), and run your commands on that single connection. Therefore I create my own `DbCommand` instances just like it was with ADO.NET alone before EF. These commands have a `Transaction` property that can be set to a `DbTransaction` instance, obtained from the connection's `BeginTransaction` method.

How does this work together with the `System.Transactions.Transaction` class? How can I add self-made database commands to such an ambient transaction?

I've tried with the `DbConnection.EnlistTransaction` method, but that would be called for every command I create. While SQL Server happily accepts that, PostgreSQL (Npgsql) rejects it with the reason that it doesn't support nested transactions. (But it's still the same transaction instance that I use here.) SQLite basically works, too, but fails when passing `null`, which would mean "no transaction".

I'm looking for a solution that lets me use `DbCommand` with the Entity Framework transactions mechanism that supports many major ADO.NET providers.

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be because you enlist multiple physical connections. `DbConnection.EnlistTransaction` is the right way to go. You just need to get out of the transaction enlistment when you are done. Closing the connection and committing the transaction should do that. Can you test if that work?

Comment: I need multiple commands in the same transaction. Since this is all provider-abstract, there's a method that creates a DbCommand which I call for every new command, and that's where I connect it with the ongoing transaction. Also, I've read that those "enlistments" are dropped automatically when a transaction has finished.

Comment: OK, so then don't close the connection until you want the transaction to end?

Comment: Correct. On a single connection, I start a transaction, which contains multiple commands. EF can't do those because it's untyped SELECT and DDL things like DROP VIEW or CREATE VIEW.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem then? It seems you know how to avoid the error and get this completely working.

Comment: No, Postgres fails. Also, I don't understand how this "enlistment" thing works internally and how I can manually bind single commands to a transaction from System.Transactions (which is not DbTransaction).

Comment: Postgres fails because you enlist multiple times. Just don't do that. Call enlist only once for each transaction. Wouldn't that solve the problem? Actually, I see no need to manually call enlist. `Open()` should be enough to auto-enlist. Then, you need to call Open exactly once.

Comment: That's exactly the point. I can't put entire new connections in the transaction, but just single commands in it. The connection is already open, now I may need new commands to be part of an ambient transaction. But not always. It should offer the same flexibility as using DbTransaction explicitly.

Comment: SQL Server also only supports one transaction at a time. I don't know about Postgres but probably it's the same. You can't switch into and back out. Once the tran is started there is no way to execute commands outside of it in the same connection.

Comment: But when the transaction is finished, I can start another one explicitly on the same connection. Most prople seem to recommend using System.Transactions over the ADO.NET DbTransaction, but fail to provide a solution for that such transactions can only span entire connections, not single commands. This is unrealistic.

Comment: I really don't see what the problem is. You seem to have the solution to everything. Just close the connection and transaction when you are done. That gets out out of the tran. Why can't you do that?